# Should I unit test each method in my Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, android-testing

I've in the past year written an Android app without doing any automated testing at all. I'm now learning about testing in Android but I still have some questions I can't seem to find answers to online.

I have unit-tested my presenters and since they don't use any Android-classes it has been pretty straight forward to write these tests.

I have also written some UI tests for my view (Fragment) using Espresso, which I also feel like I have a good grip on.

What I don't really understand is if I should write unit tests for all the methods in my Fragments as well? The UI tests check all the possible user interactions that can be done. But my Fragments still have some basic methods that are called from the presenter after it has fetched some data from model. These methods in my Fragment are really simple, they take data from presenter and use it to fill a view or toggle visibility or something similar. Should I write unit tests for these types of methods? They seem really simple but I want to make sure I understand Android testing completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

UI tests are always very brittle creatures. I once was called by my boss to check why the ui tests were failing. In the end it was because the testdevice was not connected by usb to the testserver anymore.

Also ui tests take a lot of time to run. So you have to think about what you want to achieve? When do you run your tests? Where do you want to run the tests

**Where?** Either use some kind of device lab, or if money is tight run tests on headless emulators that you create every time

**What?** Think about the big picture. *Features* You have already covered the logic of your presenters in your unit tests, now try to cover the flows in the view

**When?** If you have a big test suite, it may take hours to run. In some companies even days. Schedule the whole test suite as a nightly build. But make sure to add a reduced set of tests, the absolute core of your product to run after every commit

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are generally pointless on trivial methods.  If you have a method that just unconditionally sets a visible flag on an item, what's there to really test?

Unit testing your models and presenters should cover most potential bugs.  I wouldn't worry much about your views, especially since you're already doing UI tests.  You might want to write tests to cover bugs that come up more than once, but apart from that your time is better spent elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about test coverage. If you want to cover more of your codes, you should write tests for every method even fragment methods using mocking tools.